# How do I connect to an external database and specify the schema to use?

Tags: configuration

I want to connect Drupal to an external Database and I need to specify the schema on the settings.php file, otherwise Drupal schema module connects by default to the 'public' schema. I tried, without success, with the following code.

```
 $databases['conservation']['default'] = array(
   'database' => 'conservation',
   'schema' => 'projects_test1',
    'username' => 'xxxxxxxxxxx',
    'password' => 'xxx',
    'host' => 'xxx.xxx.xxx',
    'port' => '5432',
    'driver' => 'pgsql',
    'prefix' => array(
      'default'   => 'projects_test1.',
      'users'     => 'shared.',
      'sessions'  => 'shared.',
      'role'      => 'shared.',
      'authmap'   => 'shared.',
    )
  );
```

I have done some googling, but I haven't found anybody trying to do this.

Comment: Hi Luca 

Does this on connecting to multi databases help you at all ? https://www.drupal.org/node/18429

Comment: Thank you Deejay, but I really don't understand how to connect a specific schema, the database connection works properly but only with the public schema.

Comment: Try @david-thomas answer below and also try  `$databases['default']['default']` rather than naming the connection (unless you need to.)

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a PGSQL schema using the `prefix` setting in `settings.php`

```
 * You can also use a reference to a schema/database as a prefix. This may be
 * useful if your Drupal installation exists in a schema that is not the default
 * or you want to access several databases from the same code base at the same
 * time.
 * Example:
 *   'prefix' => array(
 *     'default'   => 'main.',
 *     'users'     => 'shared.',
 *     'sessions'  => 'shared.',
 *     'role'      => 'shared.',
 *     'authmap'   => 'shared.',
 *   );
```

More info: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/sites%21default%21default.settings.php/7 > "View Source"

If that's not working for you, make sure the rest of the database connection details are correct. (e.g you're using 'shared.' presumably that schema also exists)

Comment: Thanks, where I have to specify the name of the schema?

Comment: The schema name is the prefix, i.e everything before the "." For example in 'main.' the schema is 'main'

Comment: Ok, as done in the first answer, but doesn't work when i try to connect the tables contained on 'projects_test1'schema through the schema module. I'm able to see only the tables contained in the 'public'schema.

Comment: That might be an issue with the contrib schema module, rather than schema support per se.